# Can't click on links with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have stable version 23.0.1271.97 m and updated to Version 24.0.1312.52 m and the problem still persists.

I had installed a FRESH copy of Windows 7 on a laptop with a fresh install of chrome. No plugins no nothing.

Then to double check I went to my desktop with Windows 8 and same thing. I was surprised.

Is this a chrome bug? In chrome [on this site](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) I can't uncheck `Free! McAfee Security Scan...` option OR the `Download now` button. It does nothing.

Two different computers, one fresh setup and one long standing computer doing the same thing.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Also happens on the links at the top on [skype.com](http://skype.com)

Comment: I've been having a number of crashes and freezes with Chrome related to Flash. You might be experiencing the same problem. I tried disabling the Chrome-installed version of Flash, but it's a crap shoot as to which sites lock up and which don't.

Comment: Nope, disabled and still the same thing.

Comment: Could it be that Javascript is disabled? oo'

Comment: On a fresh install of chrome? lol no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out what it was, I had edited the host file to block some advertisement domains (which is why it didn't happen on several other sites). Weird thing is that Chrome didn't bother to connect me to the localhost loopback it just didn't let me click on anything.

So to the thousands of users that have downloaded the blacklist file to block advertisement/virus domains from

http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm

should be aware of this.

Comment: Chrome extensions that do a similar thing can also be the cause of this. That's what it ended up being for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable Native Client Plugins. Type `chrome:plugins` into the URL bar and disable Native Client.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to clear the DNS Resolver cache from your computer. Open a `cmd` and type `ipconfig /flushdns` and hit enter. DNS Resolver Cache is cleared.